# MoongoDB Aggregate function is slowest process, how to make it faster?

Tags: mongodb, performance

I am using the following aggregate function in MongoDB.

```
db.st.aggregate([  
   {  
      $project:{  
         email:{  
            $toLower:"$email"
         },
         src:1
      }
   },
   {  
      $unwind:"$src"
   },
   {  
      $group:{  
         _id:"$email",
         src:{  
            $addToSet:"$src"
         }
      }
   },
   {  
      $project:{  
         _id:0,
         email:"$_id",
         src:1
      }
   },
   {  
      $out:"poor"
   }
],
{
  allowDiskUse:true,

 })
```

The RAM I had was 32 GB, but found it less for the operations. Hence, I used the code:

```
   {
      allowDiskUse:true,

     }
```

But now the process has become slowest. I want to have the result in the fastest way so that my rest work can be done today itself. But could find a way out to make the process faster. The total data size has gone beyond the RAM size. Hence, I used the disk space option.

Kindly, help me. How can the process be made the fastest or a bit faster?

Please note that the email IDs are unique values.

My schema example: https://gist.github.com/JafferWilson/a9ac3a13da5aed29e8e89e75c082d318

Comment: Well you could get rid of the initial `$project` and do the `$toLower` on the `$group` instead, since currently this is a wasted pass through all the data. The last `$project` is also somewhat trivial and could be dropped. Noting that you are writing this out to a collection, the real question here would be "why"? Since if this is a regular process then surely the logical thing to do would be fix the code to ensure the "email" is always lower case. And if this is just a "one off" excercise, then I wonder why the complaint. It is was it is and you should never need to do it again.

Comment: Actually, I need to store the result in MongoDB. By mistake, I have inserted the emails in lowercase and uppercase. As the MongoDB is case sensitive while finding the document, I could get the document of the lowercase character but not the upper case character. Hence, I am doing this process.

Comment: @NeilLunn Can you help me?

Comment: I actually did help. You asked that question a couple of days back and I gave you an answer. If what you are trying to do is correct your existing collection then you should go back and take a look.

Comment: Thank you @NeilLunn for reminder..

Comment: @NeilLunn I am getting Memory issue with your solution. Can you tell me what I need to do?

Answer (score 0):

My approach to convert all the emailId into lower case would be as follows

```
db.collectionName.find({}).forEach(function(doc) 
{
    db.collectionName.update(
        { _id: doc._id },
        { "$set": { "emailId": doc.emailId.toLowerCase() } }
    );
});
```

This would be faster than the aggregate function

This will work perfect for collections with small number of documents.

Use Skip and Limit on the find query to get a better performance on high volume collections.

Same function shown above with Skip and Limit functions to apply on high volume collections

```
var count = db.collectionName.count()
var cont = true;

var skip = 0;
var limit = 3;

while(cont){
db.collectionName.find({}).skip(skip).limit(limit).forEach(function(doc)
{
     db.collectionName.update(
         { _id: doc._id },
         { "$set": { "emailId": doc.emailId.toLowerCase() } }
     );
 });

skip = skip+limit;
count=count-skip;
if(count<0)cont=false;
}
```

I have tried the solution with below collection and it worked fine

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5922cf16f049b1bc1ed19dd4"), "name" : "A", "emailId" : "aaAAaa@
gmail.com" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5922cf26f049b1bc1ed19dd5"), "name" : "B", "emailId" : "BBbbb@
gmail.com" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5922cf39f049b1bc1ed19dd6"), "name" : "C", "emailId" : "ccccCC@
gmail.com" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5922cf4bf049b1bc1ed19dd7"), "name" : "D", "emailId" : "dDdd@g
mail.com" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5922cf85f049b1bc1ed19dda"), "name" : "F", "emailId" : "ffFFf
f@gmail.com" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5922d146f049b1bc1ed19ddb"), "name" : "E", "emailId" : "eEeEe
eee@gmail.com" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5922df89f049b1bc1ed19ddc"), "name" : "G", "emailId" : "GGgggg@
gmail.com" }
```

---

> EDIT

Got it, your unique key prevents it from converting all the documents emailID to lowercase, if each document should have unique emailID, then converting of all documents emailId to lowercase cannot be done.

If in your case the emailId is allowed in more than one documents then, to update the emailId of all documents, We need to drop the unique index on the field emailId and then apply the above function.

Comment: The email ids are unique, so cannot do that. If there are multiple as capital value and small letter.

Comment: In a given document you will have one emailId which is unique right? Did you mean something else. I tried with an example of collection of 7 documents with each having unique emailId and the solution worked. On the safer side, take few documents of your collection and create a new collection and apply this solution, if it worked apply the solution in the original collection.

Comment: Actually, there are other values associated with the record and need to merge those values too. see the example: https://gist.github.com/JafferWilson/a9ac3a13da5aed29e8e89e75c082d318

Comment: so you want to unwind src and merge it to the main document also, in that case aggregation is the only option, but since you are facing slowness. For converting the emailID to lowercase use my approach and for merging the document use aggregate with $unwind.

Comment: You are right. But the problem is the uniqueness of the key `emailID`. hence the valuesa re not getting converted to lower case

Comment: Just make the `email` as unique key and then apply your procedures, you will come to know the problem I am facing.

Comment: I have posted the document for which I have applied the solution, please see if it helps and also I have Unique Index for the field emailID and still the solution works for me.

Comment: Check your document. but I think you haven't checked mine. Please read the question properly. See the sample is something like this: https://gist.github.com/JafferWilson/a9ac3a13da5aed29e8e89e75c082d318